# Как выбрать запись, если запросом найдена только одна запись, если больше, вернуть 0 записей?

Tags: sql, oracle

Как запросом вернуть одну запись, если по условию выборки найдена только одна запись, если больше, то запрос должен вернуть 0 записей?

То есть, для следующего запроса ожидаю:

```
create table t (val) as
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 2 from dual;

select * from t
where val = 1;

no rows selected
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to select a record if the query returns one row, or select no record if the query returns more rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15761175) от участника [@Stalin Gino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392330/stalin-gino)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/15761175

Comment: по-моему это интересный вопрос и, главное, полезен для базы знаний, поэтому было бы интересно понять мотивацию того, кто поставид минус

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо за отклик! По моему, мотивация проста, кто-то так проявляет личную неприязнь.

Answer (score 2):

В SQL запросе можно сделать что-то вроде:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over () total
    from t
    where val = 1
    and rownum <= 2
) where total= 1;

no rows selected
```

Обратите внимание, что смысл предиката `rownum <= 2` заключается в том, чтобы прервать выполнение запроса, если по условию выборки в промежуточном наборе результата будет более 2 записей. То есть, `COUNT` посчитает максимально две записи, иначе, если по условию выборки будет найдено миллионы строк, то БД сначалa посчитает их все, а затем отбросит, что разумеется крайне неэффективно.

Если запрос в PL/SQL, то при выборке в переменную с `INTO var` возникнет исключение `TOO_MANY_ROWS`, если найдено более одной записи:

```
declare
    var t%rowtype;
begin
    select * into  var
    from t
    where val = 1;
end;
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15761406) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>